# Catch every update / create in Waterline / sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to create a « Workflow » table, which register every event on every table, with some extra infos (IP, session id).

I have lots of models, and don't want to write every afterUpdate/afterCreate in every models, which is hard to maintain, plus there is no req in models to store the session id.

I don't really know how to start, that's why I'm asking if Waterline throws any event or something like that when it does any action ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [**Lifecycle Callbacks**](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Lifecyclecallbacks.html):

> Sails exposes a handful of lifecycle callbacks on models that are called automatically before or after certain actions. For example, we sometimes use lifecycle callbacks for automatically encrypting a password before creating or updating an Account model. Another example use case is automatically regenerating a URL slug when a Project's name attribute is updated.
>
> #### Callbacks on create
>
> - beforeValidate: fn(values, cb)
> - afterValidate: fn(values, cb)
> - beforeCreate: fn(values, cb)
> - afterCreate: fn(newlyInsertedRecord, cb)
>
> #### Callbacks on update
>
> - beforeValidate: fn(valuesToUpdate, cb)
> - afterValidate: fn(valuesToUpdate, cb)
> - beforeUpdate: fn(valuesToUpdate, cb)
> - afterUpdate: fn(updatedRecord, cb)
>
> #### Callbacks on destroy
>
> - beforeDestroy: fn(criteria, cb)
> - afterDestroy: fn(destroyedRecords, cb)

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I'm more thinking of lifecycle callback of **all** models, I could catch from anywhere (a service or whatever). Something like « Waterline.onCreate(function(model, event) {}) »

Comment: You can just write one `afterCreate` and tell all your models to inherit from it (using `_.extend` or similar). Otherwise, you have to write a custom hook: http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/Hooks

Comment: I've seen that I can also write an afterCreate into the `sails.config.models` but still can't get the current req at this time. Will look into hooks